# Connection reset by peer - Android request

Tags: android, http, webview, httprequest

I'm trying to check the status code error when I load a webview to check for any http errors.

Although when I try to check if my device can connect to the link https://www.google.pt/?gws_rd=ssl almost always gives the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:489)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.createTunnelToTarget(DefaultRequestDirector.java:765)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:664)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:575)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:498)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:476)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:141)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
    ... 26 more
```

I tried other links and sometimes it gives this error too, rarely it gives me http 200.

Here is how I'm doing the request:

```
class RetrieveConnectionStatus extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
        private Integer mHttpStatus;
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
                mHttpStatus = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                // if( mHttpStatus != 200) {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                L.e(CampaignScreen.class, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                mHttpStatus = 404;
            }

            return mHttpStatus;
        }
}
```

**Update:** I'm accessing via 3G and http pages also gives this error. Also via Wireless this works without a problem

Can someone help me on this? What is going on?

Comment: is your device on WIFI or 3G when doing this?

Comment: Can you access "http://" pages (non https pages)?

Comment: I'm accessing via 3G, http pages also gives these errors

Comment: what phone and 3G service are you using? it looks like your service provider may have a routing table error or other connectivity issue with the DNS resolved IP address. In other words, it is your connection, not the server you are trying to reach...

Comment: That might be true cause I tried via wireless and its working fine :(
Anything wrong with the provider?